# C# record and implement interface with nullable

Tags: c#, record, interface-implementation

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IEmailModel
{
    EmailAddressDto? Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

now I want to implement it for records. Try this:

```
public record EmailModelSendConfirmationToUserAndSuperadmin(EmailAddressDto? Receiver = null) : IEmailModel;
```

it's ok, no errors

try this:

```
public record EmailModelSendConfirmationEmailCodeToUser(string link, EmailAddressDto? Receiver = null) : IEmailModel;
```

here I get

> 'EmailModelSendConfirmationEmailCodeToUser' does not implement
> interface member 'IEmailModel.Receiver.set'.
> 'EmailModelSendConfirmationEmailCodeToUser.Receiver.init' cannot
> implement 'IEmailModel.Receiver.set'.

I really don't understand why should be implemented `set` if parameter can be nullable, but ok

I change my interface to:

```
public interface IEmailModel
{
    EmailAddressDto? Receiver { get; init; }
}
```

Class `EmailModelSendConfirmationEmailCodeToUser` no error, but class `EmailModelSendConfirmationToUserAndSuperadmin` has:

> 'EmailModelSendConfirmationToUserAndSuperadmin' does not implement
> interface member 'IEmailModel.Receiver.init'.
> 'EmailModelSendConfirmationToUserAndSuperadmin.Receiver.set' cannot
> implement 'IEmailModel.Receiver.init'.

why so and how to implement this interface for records?

Comment: Just remove the `set;`, don't replace it with `init;`.  You don't use an interface to initialize an object; the point of construction must know the final type.  (Although I suppose an interface could be important when the final type is a generic parameter, constrained by the interface)

Comment: Should work with `public EmailAddressDto? Receiver {get; init;} = null;` (or `set;`)

Comment: [Both classes work for me with `init`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABAJwFMBjAe3wBNcBRSKAGwFlSLD6BlQmCgYVJgBmUfJAAuUfgBVSAVQDOhfAEFu7AK4AHRRAphYACky5jNOvSUUKROXIAio0gH5cAJRKEoAN0W4AvLhg1enoASlwjExBcAElaaCYWNgBuTEwcAhJyKjiGZlYOLl5+IREIcX4c+j5WaXlFQwwTXAQUAAZcelgAawAacMaTSosrQht7J1d3Lx9/QOCwqNizPOTUrDxkU3jh6zsHXABvAF819NhRRQEIYkIYypX6TAPMAEghy13x5zcb6fxD3AAc0IoiSuFgUFBuBOGCOQA)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 different `IEmailModel` defined? Can you please provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Positional syntax for property definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition) section of the docs:

> When you use the positional syntax for property definition, the compiler creates:
>
> A public autoimplemented property for each positional parameter provided in the record declaration.
>
> - **For `record` types** and `readonly record struct` types: **An init-only property**.
> - For `record struct` types: A read-write property.

So either remove `set` or change it to `init`:

```
public interface IEmailModel
{
    EmailAddressDto? Receiver { get; init; } // or  just { get; }
}
```

Alternatively use "simple" property:

```
public record EmailModelSendConfirmationToUserAndSuperadmin() : IEmailModel
{
    public EmailAddressDto? Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

You can check that positional parameters for `record` types are turned by the compiler into `init` properties in [decomplication @sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABAJwFMBjAe3wBNcBRSKAGwFlSLD6BlQmCgYVJgBmUfJAAuUfgBVSAVQDOhfAEFu7AK4AHRRAphYAClrR6SihSJy5AEVGkA/LgBKJQlABui3AF5cMNfXoASlwQXABJIwZmVnoAbkwcAhJyKkimFjZObj5BYTEJGDS+Vml5RX0EFAAGXHpYAGsAGho6EzMLa1sHZ2JXD3xvX38gkPC06LZ4rDxkFuNTc0JLG1JMAG9MAF9MBLxYUUUBCF6x1on6dcwASDSFjpXul3dPNdwAc0JRWNxYKC/cbYYTZAA), note that both classes work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete `IEmailModel`.

Whatever consumes `IEmailModel` can just consume `EmailAddressDto`.

This is enough:

```
record EmailModelSendConfirmationEmailCode(string link, EmailAddressDto? Receiver = null);
```

Comment: I need an interface to use in abstract class